# Search Cmd Returns "Invalid Data" In userform

Tags: excel, vba, office365

I have an Excel VBA Data Entry userform. My "search" command keeps returning my coding error message "Invalid Data" even when my txtSearch string contains valid data. What am I missing?
Code:

```
Private Sub cmdSearch_Click()
Dim iSearch As Long, i As Long
iSearch = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
For i = 1 To iSearch
     If Trim(Sheet2.Cells(i, 1)) <> Trim(TxtSearch.Text) And i = iSearch Then
          MsgBox ("Invalid data")
          TxtSearch.Text = ""
          TxtSearch.SetFocus
     End If

     If Trim(Sheet2.Cells(i, 1)) = Trim(TxtSearch.Text) Then
          TxtLast.Text = Sheet2.Cells(i, 1)
          TxtFirst.Text = Sheet2.Cells(i, 2)
'          (Complete list of 10 text fields to populate)
Exit For
     End If
     Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: You never set/pass `TxtSearch`?

Comment: Did you check your code with the vba debugger step by step?